# Spritekit / UIBeziers: Detecting touches / nodeAtPoint

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm creating my player like this:

```
UIBezierPath *pPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(0, 0)
                                                     radius:10
                                                 startAngle:0
                                                   endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360)
                                                  clockwise:YES];
_player = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
_player.path = pPath.CGPath;
[_player setFillColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[_player setStrokeColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
_player.position = arenaCentre;
_player.zPosition = 1;
_player.name = @"player";
```

I then detect touches on this object using:

```
SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];
```

The problem is that my shape is too small/ fast to touch sometimes. How could I make the touch zone larger then the visible object?

Is there a best practice for this kind of thing?

Many thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could draw a larger shape (or color sprite) of the desired size as the parent of the player shape, and use a fully transparent color.

However this will sometimes find the parent shape, other times the actual shape. So you have to compensate for that.